# Achieve a simple grid in Boostrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to achieve this simple grid in Bootstrap:

[image]

Basically I've tried doing the following using boostrap docs:

```
<td>
<div class="row">

<div class="col">Male, Arabic, TV advertisement</div>
<div class="col">Male, Arabic, TV advertisement, Audio book children, Audio book adults announcements, TV audio description</div>

<div class="w-1"></div>

<div class="col">Male, Arabic, TV advertisement</div>
<div class="col">Male, Arabic, TV advertisement, Audio book children, Audio book adults announcements, TV audio description</div>

<div class="w-1"></div>
</div>
</td>
```

But it just comes like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should really head to the [Documentations](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) for these sort of questions, but here is a simple write-up to get you familiar with the general idea of how bootstrap grid works.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-5">
      <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
      <input type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <button>search</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      <h3>Samples</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5">
      <Component>Your Component Here</Component>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
      <Component>Your Component Here</Component>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
      <button>more</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5">
      <Component>Your Component Here</Component>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
      <Component>Your Component Here</Component>
    </div>
  </div>
  
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5">
      <Component>Your Component Here</Component>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
      <Component>Your Component Here</Component>
    </div>
  </div>
  
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5">
      <Component>Your Component Here</Component>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
      <Component>Your Component Here</Component>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Instead of using w-1, use w-100.

```
<div class="w-100"></div>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <td>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">Male, Arabic, TV advertisement</div>
      <div class="col">
        Male, Arabic, TV advertisement, Audio book children, Audio book adults announcements, TV audio description
      </div>

      <div class="w-100"></div>

      <div class="col">Male, Arabic, TV advertisement</div>
      <div class="col">
        Male, Arabic, TV advertisement, Audio book children, Audio book adults announcements, TV audio description
      </div>

      <div class="w-100"></div>

      <div class="col">Male, Arabic, TV advertisement</div>
      <div class="col">
        Male, Arabic, TV advertisement, Audio book children, Audio book adults announcements, TV audio description
      </div>

    </div>
  </td>
</body>

</html>
```